# date-format not working on html page with datepicker

Tags: django, forms, date-format

First, I'm relatively new to Django. I've seen my question addressed here with answers that I've tried to implement without success. Using a date picker that formats the date differently then how its stored and returned on the form initially.

forms.py

```
....
start_date = forms.Datefield(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y'),   input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y'])
```

queries.html

```
....
  <div class="col-4">
  <label for="start_date" style="font-weight: bold;">Start Date</label>
     <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
       <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" value="{{queryform.start_date.value}}" class="form-control">
       <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></div>
     </div>
   </div>
 ....
   <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <script>
                $(function() {
                  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                     changeMonth: true,
                     dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
                     changeYear: true,
                     yearRange: "2010:2025"
                    });
                 });
            </script>
```

url.py

```
path('editqueries/<id>', views.editqueries, name='editqueries'),
```

views.py

```
def editqueries(request, id):

query_data = get_object_or_404(Query, pk=id)

if request.method == "POST":
    query_form = QueryForm(request.POST, instance=query_data)
    if query_form.is_valid():
        the_query_name = query_form.cleaned_data["query_name"]
        # get the hidden field from the html page (but not on the 
        # Django form)
        current_query_name = request.POST["currentqueryname"]

        # test to be sure if the names are not the same that changing 
        # the name doesn't create a duplicate query_name
        if not the_query_name == current_query_name:
            try:
                test_query = 
                    Query.objects.get(query_name=the_query_name)
            except Query.DoesNotExist:
                # this is allowed.  Named changed does not create a 
                # duplicate
                query_form.save()
                query = Query.objects.all()
                query_flag = "None"
                context = {'queries': query, 'query_flag': query_flag}
                return render(request, 'seakerUI/queries.html', 
                              context)        

            # successful query means this name is in use.  
            # Stop the renaming of the query.
            return HttpResponse("ERROR: Query Name '" + 
                                the_query_name + "' Already exist!")

        query_form.save()
        query = Query.objects.all()
        query_flag = "None"
        context = {'queries': query, 'query_flag': query_flag}
        return render(request, 'seakerUI/queries.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Form is invalid.. errors:" + 
                            str(query_form.errors))
else:
    query_form = QueryForm(instance=query_data)
    # tell the user the query is ready to be updated.
    query_flag = "Edit"
    context = {'queryform': query_form, 'query_flag': query_flag}

return render(request, 'seakerUI/queries.html', context)
```

queries.html

```
see code above
```

So when attempting to edit a query, the page is formatted with the date like "Aug. 2, 2019".  However, if one submits the form without changing the date, the form is invalid and the form.error is date is invalid.

I've set the following line in settings.py

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%m/%d/$Y']
```

I've had 2 other formats in  this definition but none seem to work.
I also executed

```
python manage.py diffsettings
```

and though it shows in the output the impact is negligible.

I've attempted using many examples of structuring the forms.py file using a widget function and without it without success. The problem does not appear to be with the javascript on the hmtl page.

NOTE: If I change the date when the edit query page presents it then the form validates.  However, if one doesn't change the date and the form is submitted it is not valid and an error occurs.  I shouldn't have to change the date to get the form to validate.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the entire error traceback also, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with html5 and WTF forms.
Html5 and WTFforms together can be used to select and date/month/year and process.

In form.py:
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateField

Accept the inputs as shown :
dob= DateField('Password - Your Date of Birth', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%Y-%m-%d')

In html
form.dob(class="form-control form-control-lg")